# Run bash command on multiple files at once

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a bunch of files that end in numbers (ex filename_01.txt, filename_02.txt, etc).  Is there a way to run a bash command on a subset of these files in one call? Ie pseudo code:

```
cp filename_0{1:4} new_dir/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at two ways you can match files -- one with curly braces, and one with square braces. It's good to understand the difference.

```
cp filename_0{1..4} new_dir/
```

This expands into four filenames. Preface the command line with `echo` to see what you're actually running.

```
cp filename_0[1-4] new_dir/
```

This expands into all the existent files that match the pattern.

This isn't so subtle a difference. In the first case, if any file is missing, you'll see an error. In the second case, your command line will match all the files that exist, but there's no requirement for them to exist. If getting an error is important to you (because all these files *should* exist), choose your method accordingly.

Note that the curly brace notation, at least in bash version 4, can also handle increments, so you can do the following:

```
$ echo file{10..30..4}
file10 file14 file18 file22 file26 file30
```

I should point out that the `[1-4]` notation, while it looks like it might be part of a regular expression, [is not](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46444/13377). It's part of Pathname Expansion, documented fully in the bash man page (`man bash`). You should probably read about `failglob` and `extglob` while you're in a documentation-reading mood.

I should point out that neither of these cases handles zero padding on its own. In your example, and in the answers so far (including mine), the numbers are zero padded manually.  If you want a more flexible approach that lets you work with arbitrary/unknown numbers of digits, you'll need to use a more advanced tool, presumably that understands printf-style formats. But that's probably an answer for another question. :-)

Comment: if I wanted to use the files as input to a bash script would the `{}` notation work? The script only recognizes one file at a time and I'm trying to figure out if this notation works like a for loop or a list

Comment: If your bash script reads from standard input, then you can simply cat the pattern (whichever one you need, per your requirement for errors) then pipe the output of cat into the script. That's what `cat` is for -- to concatenate files. Alternately, if your bash script always processes the first command line option as an input file, `man xargs`, and perhaps use `xargs -n 1` to process a list of files. The way you use "a bash script" really depends on the bash script. If you want help with that script, perhaps it would be best to post another question and include the script's source.

Answer (score 2):

You can use brackets to expand file names :

```
cp filename_0[1-4].txt new_dir/
```

will copy `filename_01.txt`, `filename_02.txt`, `filename_03.txt`, `filename_04.txt` to `new_dir`.

Comment: would this still work if I was using the giving the filenames to a bash script?

Comment: It will work with every command where a file name is expected.